# How does a custom SOAP header relate to a custom WCF header?

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, header, soapheader

I am trying to send more info in each message from the client (Mobile Device) to my service.  In my research I am finding about [interceptors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050554/wcf-interceptor-on-compact-framework) and [custom wcf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059533/wcf-how-to-create-a-custom-header-sent-from-a-compact-framework-client) headers.

Now I am starting to see stuff about [custom SOAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976217/how-to-add-custom-soap-headers-in-wcf) headers.

What is the difference?

Comment: WCF messages = SOAP messages, therefore WCF headers = SOAP headers (as long as you don't use the webHttpBinding, which is REST instead of SOAP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, the result is the same. WCF provides you the option of taking different paths to get there. Using [message contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730255.aspx) gives you explicit control over how your messages are shaped and what is contained in the header and the body.

If you already have defined data contracts, then the [other approach](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2006/04/23/141.aspx) will allow you to add headers to your existing message structure.